# Почему  "закавыка" пишется через "А"?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Этимологические словари дают происхождение от к**о**выка, письмо у  нас довольно-таки "окающее" (м**о**локо, с**о**бака), да и у Даля через "о" слово написано - "зак**о**выка".

Может кто знает с чем связано написание через "А"? Вот такая вот зак**а**выка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С распространением аканья. В др.-русск. было ковыка, ковычька, со временем аканье закрепилось в письме в некоторых словах. Где-то в 14 веке появляются памятники письменности с аканьем. Наверно, тогда и ковыка стало кавыкой.

Comment: >В др.-русск. было ковыка, ковычка   
 
А с каким значением? 
Про источники даже не спрашиваю ))))

Comment: Вики.Значение не менялось, Надюшка про него всё сказала, автор вопроса  и сам знает, а о влиянии аканья на письмо:Теория аканья:  http://5fan.ru/wievjob.php?id=1688 29.Отражение аканья в памятниках письменности: прямым отражением аканья в узком смысле слова - считается замена буквы О буквой А. Един. случаи отражения аканья появляются в памятниках письменности лишь начиная с 14 века. ( прикаснуся, прадающем, вертаград – московское евангелие 1393 г.)
http://textfighter.org/raznoe/Linguist/meshch/kak_pokazyvaet_analiz_drevneishih_pamyatnikov_moskovskoi_pismennosti_gosudarstva_territorii.php

Comment: Смею напомнить, что кавычки появились в русском языке не ранее XVIII века. Какое уж тут "значение не менялось"...

История появления кавычек

Интересна история появления знака, который впоследствии получил название кавычки [» «]. Слово «кавычки» в значении нотного (крюкового) знака встречается в XVI веке, но в значении знака препинания оно стало употребляться только в конце XVIII века. Предполагают, что инициатива введения этого знака препинания в практику русской письменной речи (как и тире) принадлежит Н. М. Карамзину...
http://100-000-pochemu.info/id/979

Comment: Да что ж Вы всё переиначиваете... Я сказала, что "ковычки" и "кавычки" - одно и то же, значение не менялось, а как и от чего образовалось - в этимологических словарях есть.Автору и без меня и без Вас  всё известно. То Вы насчёт "окающего письма" Марка не поняли, то меня не понимаете...Всё Вы понимаете... как Вам надо.А "О" и "А" путают из-за того, что письмо древнерусское было то "окающим", то "акающим". (Ссылку дала выше) В подробности, почему так, не будем вдаваться, оно нам не надо, пусть учёные разбираются.

Answer (score 2):

На сайте грамма.ру дается вот такой ответ на этот вопрос: Этимология слова "закавыка" остается не вполне ясной, хотя не вызывает сомнений его родственная связь с названием пунктуационного знака "кавычки". Уже в XIV в. встречается термин "кавыка" как название надстрочного знака и какого-то знака препинания. Принимая во внимание такие данные, как украинское название кавычек "лапки", русское "птичка" - наименование письменного знака v, не должно казаться невероятным сопоставление с русским диалектным "кавыш" - утёнок, гусёнок, "кавка" - лягушка, "кавыкать" - ковылять, прихрамывать. Таким образом, "кавычки", "кавыки" - следы от утиных или лягушачьих лапок > крючок, закорючка. Ср. устар."кавыка" - каракуля, завитушка на письме.

В словаре В. Даля: "КАВЫКА, кавычка ж. крючковатый значок в письме: запятая, кратка; кавычки, знаки для вносных или чужих слов (<). Тут есть кавычка, помеха, заминка, препятствие. Кавыкать или кувыкат. ь, хромать, прихрамывать, ковылять; плестись, тащиться кой-как, жить с горем пополам. Не привыкать кувыкать (см. кувериться).".

Но при этом, как вы правильно заметили, у того же Даля есть слово ЗАКОВЫКА, -чка ж. | запятая; | *крючок, помеха. Заковычки, двойная запятая, означающая вводную речь, две ковычки ("). Заковычный, к заковычке относящийся. Заковычливый, охочий до заковычек. Заковычить речь, поставить в заковычки, означив тем, что она вводная, чужая, что говоришь по говоренному; то же, что выражает наше мол, мл, де, дескать.

Получается, что путаница и здесь, но точно видно по значению, что слова близки.

Comment: Как раз ответа-то и не даётся.

Comment: Заковыристым оказался вопрос про закавыку...

Answer (score 1):

Так и "кавычка" через А.
О и А часто переходят друг в друга, в школе изучаются только те случаи, котолрые представляют практический интерес. Реально их много больше, объясняется это происхождением современной системы гласных. Русские А и О происходят не от разных праиндоевропейских, но от разной их долготы.

Это версия. А реально - надо смотреть время образования каждого слова в русском. Если они достаточно древние, то версия получит весомый аргумент в свою пользу.

Заявления насчет "окающего" письма вообще не понял.